# Calculating distance between consecutive projected coordinates within individuals (adding distance column?)

Tags: r, coordinates, distance, r-sf

I have a movement dataset with different individuals and projected coordinates. The coordinates were projected into UTM using the following code:

```
coordinates(data) = ~x+y #turns data into spatial data frame
proj4string(data) <- CRS("+init=epsg:4326")
data <- spTransform(data, CRS("+init=epsg:5321")) #denotes what CRS to use, this changes the data into UTMs from lat/long, which projects the data
data <- as.data.frame(data)
```

I would like to calculate the distance in meters between consecutive locations within individuals. I'm okay with a pretty large margin of error as long as it is consistent between points.

Here is a sample of my dataset:

```
ID      x         y    
Bear1   459486.4  7181992
Bear1   459652.6  7181904
Bear1   459661.5  7181880
Bear2   459604.7  7181898
Bear2   459639.6  7181894
Bear2   459565.1  7181960
```

Optimally, I'd love a distance column added to this dataset, showing the distance within points.

Comment: You will need to provide more information, namely the coordinate system of the projection.  In the meantime take a look at the sf package.

Comment: Thank you for your help. The coordinates are in UTM projection. I'll edit the question to specify this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please find below a reprex that shows a solution with the `sf` package.

If I am not wrong, the data you provide are already in EPSG:5321. Assuming this, you only need to enter the following lines of code to get a distance matrix between all the possible pairs of points.

**Reprex**

- Code

```r
library(sf)

data <- st_as_sf(data, coords = c("x", "y"), crs = 5321)
distances <- st_distance(data)
distances
#> Units: [m]
#>           [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]      [,5]      [,6]
#> [1,]   0.00000 188.05967 207.85574 151.09894 181.86325  84.95699
#> [2,] 188.05967   0.00000  25.59707  48.27432  16.40122 103.88575
#> [3,] 207.85574  25.59707   0.00000  59.58389  25.99250 125.27155
#> [4,] 151.09894  48.27432  59.58389   0.00000  35.12848  73.56738
#> [5,] 181.86325  16.40122  25.99250  35.12848   0.00000  99.53015
#> [6,]  84.95699 103.88575 125.27155  73.56738  99.53015   0.00000
```

<sup>Created on 2021-10-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

If you want to start from scratch, that is, from geographic coordinates (i.e. EPSG = 4326), you have to proceed as follows:

```r
library(sf)

data <- st_as_sf(data, coords = c("x", "y"), crs = 4326)
data <- st_transform(data, crs = 5321)
distances <- st_distance(data)
distances
```

- Your data

```r
data <- data.frame(ID = c("Bear1", "Bear1", "Bear1", "Bear2", "Bear2", "Bear2"),
                   x = c(459486.4, 459652.6, 459661.5, 459604.7, 459639.6, 459565.1),
                   y = c(7181992, 7181904, 7181880, 7181898, 7181894, 7181960))
```

---

**EDIT TO ANSWER YOUR COMMENT**

```r
library(sf)
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
library(units)

# Same code as above (but in a tidyverse version and with drop_units function) to get the distance matrix (i.e. data2)
data2 <- data %>% st_as_sf(coords = c("x", "y"), crs = 5321) %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  st_distance() %>% 
  drop_units()

# Extraction of the relevant values from the distance matrix 
data2 <- setnames(setDT(as.data.frame(data2[row(data2) == col(data2)+1])), 1, "Distance")

# Add a NA row at the end of data2
data2 <- rbindlist(list(data2, list(NA)))[, Index := 1:.N][]

# Join data and data2 on 'Index' column
Results <- setDT(data)[, Index :=  1:.N
                       ][data2, on = .(Index)
                         ][, Index := NULL][]

# Set NA at the last row of each group (i.e. each Bear) for the 'Distance' column
Results[Results[, .(idLast = .I[.N]), by=ID]$idLast, Distance := NA][]
#>       ID        x       y  Distance
#> 1: Bear1 459486.4 7181992 188.05967
#> 2: Bear1 459652.6 7181904  25.59707
#> 3: Bear1 459661.5 7181880        NA
#> 4: Bear2 459604.7 7181898  35.12848
#> 5: Bear2 459639.6 7181894  99.53015
#> 6: Bear2 459565.1 7181960        NA
```

<sup>Created on 2021-11-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks! I was specifically looking for distances between consecutive locations though (my bad - I edited the question to show this). Would you happen to know how to do this?

Comment: Hello @Cam. Please find above an edit to answer your comment. I hope this is what you want. If so, please mark the answer as validated. If not, please, tell me what is wrong. Cheers.

Comment: That's perfect, thank you!

Comment: Glad that I could help you. I wish you the best for your work. Cheers.